# How do I do this via RxJs?

Tags: rxjs

I have a autocomplete control that triggers a onAutoCompleteSearch() after a debounce where I retrieve results from the server.  However, if the user enters text and hits enter (key code 13) then a signal should be raised that will cancel the **next** invocation of an autocomplete.  Since this is a 3rd party control I don't have control over the invocation of onAutoCompleteSearch() that occurs after a set debounce time.

I am using a Subject to do the signalling:

```
private cancelAutoComplete$ = new Subject<boolean>();
```

If user hits enter key:

```
  onKeyUp(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      this.cancelAutoComplete$.next(true);   
      this.fireExecuteSearch();   // fire full search
    } else {
      this.fireSearchChange();    // trigger user input change
    }
  }
```

When an autocomplete is to be executed:

```
  onAutoCompleteSearch(e) {
    console.log('starting autocomplete!');

    this.cancelAutoComplete$
      .first()
      .defaultIfEmpty(false)
      .subscribe(c => {
        if (c) {
          console.log('autocomplete cancelled!');
        } else {
          console.log('execute the autocomplete!');
          this.executeAutoComplete.next(e.query);
        }
      });
  }
```

the above does not quite work... what I wish to do is check the cancelAutoComplete stream for an element, if one exists then take it off the stream, if the cancel flag is true then abort the autocomplete.  If there isn't an element then return a default element of false so I can continue with the autocomplete.

How can I accomplish this?  Basically if there is an cancel signal pending from the onKeyUp -> keycode 13 event I want to abort the call, if not continue.

I know I can use a simple boolean to track this but wanted to know how to do it via RxJs Subjects.

Comment: Is it just a case of making cancelAutoComplete$ a BehaviorSubject initialised to false?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd make `cancelAutoComplete$` a BehaviorSubject initialised to `false`. Send it `false` whenever the keyCode is not 13:

```
private cancelAutoComplete$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

onKeyUp(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    this.cancelAutoComplete$.next(true); // prevent autocomplete
    this.fireExecuteSearch();   
  } else {
    this.cancelAutoComplete$.next(false); // allow autocomplete   
    this.fireSearchChange();
  }
}
```

Then I'd use the [takeUntil](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html) operator as part of your `executeAutoComplete` stream as follows:

```
onAutoCompleteSearch(e) {
  this.executeAutoComplete.next(e.query);
}

this.executeAutoComplete
  .switchMap(query => this.backend.fetchAutoCompleteResults(query).takeUntil(
     this.cancelAutoComplete$.filter(c => c === true)
  ))
  .subscribe(...);
```

I've assumed your backend api is named `this.backend.fetchAutoCompleteResults` - the takeUntil will abort it if `cancelAutoComplete$` is initially `true` or becomes `true` while the call is in flight.